# Vimdiff: Highlight current change in all buffers

Tags: git, vim, vimdiff, vim-fugitive

I'm using Tim Pope's [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin to integrate git features into Vim.

When I run `Gdiff` on a conflicted file, it fires up vimdiff to resolve the conflict.

The diff tool is great but I find it really hard to know at a glance which changes on the buffers on the sides correspond to the change my cursor is at in the middle buffer. I would like to configure it so that whenever I go to the next change (with `[c`) it would not only move my cursor to the next change but also highlight the corresponding changes on the sides. Is that possible?

Comment: That is the default behavior.

Comment: It doesn't for me. Maybe it has something to do with my color scheme. What do you use?

Comment: It could be, although it is also subject to the severity / complexity of the actual changes, sometimes, especially if you have a lot of removed lines etc it can be difficult to 'sync' buffers to show the actual changes across different versions simultaneously. But for the most part it should work that way. Check out the vimcasts for the same.